# There is no way to use app password on gmail account trough django app

Tags: django, smtplib

I have running in production a django app, the webapp has a function in order to send emails with attachment to some guys using a gmail account through app password option . The functionallity worked OK for more than 3 years until a couple of days when show up this error in the errorlog:
App 2165051 output: smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'Incorrect authentication data')

Things that i've already checked:
1.- When I checked the app password of gmail account there wasn´t anyone. ( weird, it seems that dissapeared)
2.- I created a new one, replace the new password in my code and still showing 535 error.
3.- I've create trhee app passwords and still no luck.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@adicra.org.ar'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py

```
#Vista de enviar por mail

class pagosMailPdfView(View):

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        print("Aca en pagosMailPdfView")

        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP(settings.EMAIL_HOST,settings.EMAIL_PORT)

        #print(mailServer.ehlo())

        mailServer.starttls()

        #print(mailServer.ehlo())
        print(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER)
        print(settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
        mailServer.login(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)


        print("conectando...")

        # averiguo la dirección de email del socio

        pagoh=PagosHead.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        emailsocio=pagoh.numero_socio.email
```

I assume that the problem is related to the google account configuration. Does anybody knows    how to check this?

Thanks in Adavance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

**An Update**: Ive been figuring out what happened with this issue with no luck.

**The workaround**: I set up a different email account (no google one) and is working OK with the same configuration so the problem is with that google email account.